# JQuery - Ajax get Request - doesn't return me the "extracts" or "exintro" (summary) property in the response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

In general I'm working on a little webapp that just shows me search entries from wikipedia on the page after I enter a search term into the textfield. 
I’m working on this problem a long time now.
I have setup an ajax get request to the wikipedia api.

It’s working fine as far as the title goes. But I looked at the json I get in return via console.log and see that there is no summary or first paragraph in this response.

So I googled and found a very nice article which points me to that link:

(can't post it due to under 10 reputation, sad story)
Just google for "wikipedia extracts api"

It says that the query also needs this prop=“extracts” and the exintro: true
But if I add this to my query I do not get the "exintro" in return.

**Here is how I set up my ajax call:**

```
function callback(){ // gets called when sliding up the div is completed 
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',
        //TODO: Fix this line of code (extracts)
        data: { action: 'query', list: 'search', prop: 'extracts', exintro: true, srsearch: $("input[name=search]").val(), format: 'json' },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: processResult
    });
    $(".container").remove();
}
```

**So if it’s successfull it runs the processResultmethod:**

```
function processResult(apiResult){
    console.log(apiResult);
    for (var i = 0; i < apiResult.query.search.length; i++){
         $('#display-result').append('<div class="' + i + '">' + '<p>'+apiResult.query.search[i].title+'</p>'  + '<p>'+ apiResult.query.search[i].snippet +'</p>' +  '</div>');
    }
 }
```

**But the json it returns looks something like that:**

[Picture of the returned json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5mb6.png)

Nothing I’m interested in. I need the summary or exintro how wiki api calls this.

Here is the link to the github: https://github.com/dhuber666/wikipediaJS

Any ideas? Do I set it up wrong in the ajax call object “data” ? Pleae help!
The snippetin the json is useless since it cuts off the sentence after a few words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "data" object is fine. Seems like "snippet" is just what Wikimedia API returns for this request. You can then send request to get extracts of returned pages (using "title" or "pageid" you get for each article). For example: [https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=true&explaintext=true&titles=Title|Hello](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=true&explaintext=true&titles=Title%7CHello) for titles "Title" and "Hello".

Maybe [this other API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Opensearch) call will suit your needs:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=hello&format=json It returns one full sentence, doesn't cut anything.

Comment: Ah okay I think I know what you mean. So I have to first grab the data and make another api call with the pageid and then I can fetch other data. That will help thank you